# How do I format an NSString over multiple lines

Tags: objective-c

Does anyone know how to format an NSString over multiple lines?

e.g. this doesn't build:

```
return @"asdfasdf" +
        "asdfasdf";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return @"asdfasdf"
       @"asdfasdf";
```

I suggest using this syntax instead of

```
return @"asdfasdf"
       "asdfasdf";
```

just to distinguish C-strings from ObjectiveC ones.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this problem all the time (especially with HTML strings), so I made a tiny tool to convert text to an escaped multi-line Objective-C string:

http://multilineobjc.herokuapp.com/

Hope this saves you some time.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `+`, the compiler will join the two strings together. See [C syntax: string literal concatenation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#String_literal_concatenation).

```
return @"asdfasdf"
        "asdfasdf";
```

Note that neither GCC nor LLVM seem to care if you omit the `@` prefix from the later strings.